# Finding all primes below a given limit with this partial code

Tags: python, primes

I got stuck with this example. I don't know how to set the correct logical operation in the while.

Here is the text:

Finding all primes below a given limit with this partial code. Fill the blanks.
To check a prime number, you have to divid all the previous prime numbers.

```
def primes(n):
    p = []
    for k in __________:
        i = 0
        while i < ________ and __________ != 0:
            i += 1
        if i == _________:
            p.append(____)
    return p
```

Here is my attempt:

```
def prastevila(n):
    p = []
    for k in range(2, n + 1):
        i = 0
        while i < k and k % (i + 1) != 0:
            i += 1
        print i
        if i == 0:
            p.append(k)
    return p
```

Comment: Did your attempt work?

Comment: Where did you get this example? This is certainly not the easiest way to find a list of primes.

Comment: My attempt didn't work. You can't change the value of i to 2. You have to replace the empty spaces with code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my solution considering already in list primes:

```
def prastevila(n):
    p = []
    for k in range(2, n + 1):
        i = 0
        while i < len(p) and k % p[i] != 0:
            i += 1
        if i == len(p):
            p.append(k)
    return p

#In [2]: prastevila(20)
#Out[2]: [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19]
```

Comment: I don't think that this what your teacher is expecting. Maybe you should use `i` to iterate over the already found primes and not over all numbers below your candidate. As you stated: "To check a prime number, you have to divid all the previous prime numbers."

Comment: I edited the answer, because its true that it wasnt the solution that the teacher would expect. Now it use already in list primes.

Comment: @CCP +1. Also looking at the snippet given by the teacher, one could suspect that their understanding of python is rather limited.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what the `while` is good for (I abused it for a simple `if`). This is a horrible way to find primes, but it does work:

```
def primes(n):
    p = []
    for k in range (2, n + 1):
        i = 0
        while i < 1 and all (k % p for p in p) != 0:
            i += 1
        if i == 1:
            p.append(k)
    return p
```

---

Output for `primes(100)`:

`[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97]`

---

It is the same as:

```
def primes(n):
    p = []
    for k in range (2, n + 1):
       if all (k % p for p in p):
            p.append(k)
    return p
```

But I had to fill in the blanks.

Comment: yes, horrible. can you express `all (k % p for p in p such that p*p <= n)` ?

Comment: @WillNess I don't understand your question. Could you please elaborate.

Comment: you should stop early. you must not test `k` by all preceding primes, but only by such that `p*p <= k`. (not `<= n`, but `<= k`, that was an error).

Comment: @WillNess Gotcha. Something like `all (k % p for p in (p for p in p if p**2 <= k) )`? Lol, or just `all (k % p for p in p if p**2 <= k)`.

Comment: whatever works by bailing out early. testing all of them is no good. When the first is detected, the rest are guaranteed to fulfill the `if`. I don't think your expression will bail out early.

Comment: @WillNess Also the `range(2, n + 1)` is a stupidity in this context. As is trial division per se. I think this is just an academic problem without need for optimization. Nobody would use trial division to find primes in the real world.

Comment: depends, in which range. optimal TD is good up to 100k - 500k. your code is only good up to 500, hardly 1000. optimal TD is ~n^1.5 or so; yours is ~n^2.

Comment: @WillNess The problem is that his assignment explicitly states that "To check a prime number, you have to divid all the previous prime numbers.". Which is not true, but maybe binding for the pupils.

Comment: oh, yes. hmm. why would they say that?......... ? anyway it doesn't demand of _you_ to post the terrible monstrosity which should be easy enough to fix. well, I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

Another option using banana pancakes:

```
def primes(n):
    p = []
    for k in range(2, n + 1):
        i = 0
        while i < len('banana') and 'pancakes' != 0:
            i += 1
        if i == 6 * int(all(k % p for p in p)):
            p.append(k)
    return p
```

And another one using strawberry shortcake:

```
def primes(n):
    p = []
    for k in ('strawberry',):
        i = 0
        while i < len('short') and 'cake' != 0:
            i += 1
        if i == i:
            p.append((lambda t: p.extend(t[:-1]) or t[-1])([a for a in range(2, n + 1) if all(a % c for c in range(2, a))]))
    return p
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a fill in the blanks and must use the code as shown and must divide by the already found primes.

```
def primes(n)
  p = []
  for k in range(2, n):
  i = 0
  while i < len(p) and (k % p[i]) != 0:
    i += 1
  if i == len(p):
   p.append(k)
  return p
```

The while will end as soon as a prime value that divides the candidate is found.
This does work as I tried it and printed p after the return.